# Add-Member output to CSV file is System.Object[]

Tags: powershell

I am trying an inventory script and I am fetching sub net details and piping it to a CSV file. But the output is `System.Object[]` instead of IP address.

[image]

I want IP address to be piped in its original form, for example `255.255.0.0`.

```
$nmconfiginfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $s

Add-Member -InputObject $infoObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IP Subnet" -Value $nmconfiginfo.IPSubnet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IPSubnet` property contains a collection of all of the IP Subnets for all of the interfaces returned. For example the value of mine is:

```
255.255.255.0
64
255.255.252.0
64
255.255.255.0
64
255.255.240.0
64
```

If you want this full value to be returned, you could do that by piping to `Out-String`:

```
Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "IP Subnet" -value ($nmconfiginfo.IPSubnet | Out-String)
```

However if you want the subnet value of a specific interface then you'll need to narrow down the `$nmconfiginfo` collection to that specific interface first, for example:

```
$nmconfiginfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $s | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq 'Name of the interface you want'}
```

Beware that Description is not necessarily a unique field (so you might still get multiple results). You could consider filtering by another field, e.g `IPAddress`.

Comment: Definitely filter it down to the actual interface you want (You can provide this filter in the WMI query in most cases, not just after retrieving the data, depending on the results speed of response will vary depending which side you do the filtering on)

Comment: @Mark Wragg Thankyou, marked your's as answer as it helped me in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

`IPSubnet` is an array.  One way you could get this into a single item is to create a string from the individual values.  For example, replace:

```
-Value $nmconfiginfo.IPSubnet
```

with:

```
-Value (($nmconfiginfo.IPSubnet | Where-Object {$_ -match "(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}"}) -join ';')
```

This will populate the property with a string, where each subnet is separated by a semi-colon, leaving out any invalid entries.